# How to write a SQL query for finding more than percent average?

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing customer_id, customer_name, month_day, month, total_sales. The data looks like the following way

```
customer_id     customer_name   month_day   month       total_sales
   1            ravi            2           Feb         479892.901
   2            arun            7           Aug         889390.709
   3            goutham         6           Sep         791831.561
   4            naveen          8           Sep         797413.558
```

Here the average of total_sales is 739632.18 and its 5% is 36981.6 and the total is 776613.78. I want to get the total_sales in between this 776613.78 and 739632.18 on Sep.

Comment: With that sample table data, what is the expected result? Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Give expected result

Comment: In that sample data, the average of total_sales is 739632.18 and its 5% is 36981.6 and the total is 776613.78. I need the total_sales in between this 776613.78 and 739632.18.                                 
SELECT * FROM sales WHERE total_sales = (SELECT (0.05*(total_sales)) + AVG(total_sales) as average FROM sales WHERE month = 'Sep' and month_day = 1)

Answer (score 0):

Did you need something like this:

```
SELECT customer_id FROM a 
WHERE month_day = 6 and month = 'Apr' --Date and Month filter
and total_sales > (SELECT (AVG(total_sales)*1.05) FROM a WHERE month_day = 6 and month = 'Apr');
```

I'm a bit confuse that why you don't have same `customer_id` when this is sales table

This is a query in case this is order transactions that `customer_id` isn't a pk

```
SELECT customer_id FROM a 
WHERE month_day = 6 and month = 'Apr' 
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING SUM(total_sales) > (SELECT (AVG(total_sales)*1.05) FROM a WHERE month_day = 6 and month = 'Apr');
```

Hope its help

Answer (score 0):

It's not super clear to me, but maybe this?

```
SELECT *
FROM sales,
  (SELECT avg(total_sales) AS avgval
   FROM sales
   WHERE month = 'Sep') tabavg
WHERE month = 'Sep'
      AND day = '1'
      AND total_sales > tabavg.avgval
      AND total_sales < tabavg.avgval * 1.05;
```